# Correct or not? "I'm so happy having found you."

Tags: question-tags

Is this sentence correct?

> I'm so happy having found you.

or is it better to say:

> I'm so happy to have found you.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would use "I'm happy I found you!" instead!

Answer (score 0):

Using the word "having" would sound nice in a narration:

> *Having found her, he was happy once more.*

But in actual speech, one should certainly use "have":

> *I'm so happy to have found you.*

Both of these convey a somewhat serious sense — like if the person were lost for some time. In a more lighthearted scenario, such as if you stumbled across a friend from some years ago, it would be better to state your happiness so:

> *I'm happy I found you!*